# activity stream based on logged jira-user

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

Are they any API OR Gadget can be created which will provide output based on the current logged users. This will be a 'acitivty stream'.

Answer (score 2):

An activity stream of your (current user logged in) activity can be found in your profile. Click on upper right corner on your avatar and then Profile. You should see an activity stream at right part of the screen. You can then filter it by few predefined filters such: *Assigned, Assigned & Opened, Reported, Voted,* etc.

Comment: That does; but I'm looking for have gadgets based on filters.

Comment: You can customize Actvity Stream gadget, and filter the stream by _Project, Username, Jira Issue Key, Update Date, Issue Type_. Ofcourse you will need to create a new dashboard or edit existed one first.